# window.location.href not working from SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert2

I have a `sweetAlert` popup when user selects delete button on a modal form which should redirect the user to the page that handles the delete. The `sweetAlert` is showing up correctly. I am temporarily logging `theHREF` to the console and can tell it is correct, if I move the `console.log` to the redirect function `theHREF` is not shown in the console.

Note: The modal is generated for each item in a loop, I have verified that the `data-bale-id` passed from the modal is for the correct item the user has selected.

Code that calls sweetAlert:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-flat pull-left delete-bale" data-bale-no="<%= baleNo%>" data-bale-id="<%= baleID%>" data-fb-id="<%= fbID%>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

Here is sweetAlert:

```
//Delete Bale Sweet Alert
$('a.delete-bale').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
        var fbId = $(this).attr("data-fb-id");
        var baleId = $(this).attr("data-bale-id");
        var baleNo = $(this).attr("data-bale-no");
        var theHREF = "bale_delete.asp?fbid=" + fbId + "&fbdid=" + baleId;
        console.log(theHREF);
        warnBeforeRedirect(baleNo,theHREF);
      });

      function warnBeforeRedirect(baleNo,theHREF) {
        swal({
          title: "Delete", 
          text: "Are you sure that you want to delete this bale? " + baleNo, 
          type: "question",
          confirmButtonColor: '#e45847',
          confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete',
          showCancelButton: true
        }, function() {
          // Redirect the user
          window.location.href = theHREF;
          return false;
        });
      }
```

When the Confirmation button within the `sweetAlert` is selected, nothing happens. The `sweetAlert` simply disappears and you are returned to the modal.

Comment: What version of SweetAlert are you using? Scratch that - I see the version in the tag now.  I can't see an example of using callbacks with SweetAlert 2 - only promises.  Have you tried using `.then()`?

Comment: check out the https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2

Comment: I bet that is the problem, I jumped over to SweetAlert2 to use some of the customization features they have added, never thought about other functionality not working anymore. Thx,

Comment: @LimonMonte, thanks for the link. I was able to sort my issue!